# JS match method with case insensitive doesn't work properly in IE/Chrome?

Tags: javascript, match, case-insensitive

I've got the following keyword matcher:

http://jsfiddle.net/y8Gd4/

If one types for example "un", "Sun" or "Spa" it returns true for the first div with `data-keywords` attr with value "Sun" or second with "Spain".

But if one types "sun" or "spa" it returns false for both divs in IE 7/8/9 and Chrome 28.0 although there's an option which should make the method case insensitive.

In FF 22.0 it works fine.

Any idea why IE/Chrome omits the "i" insensitive flag?

Comment: Not sure where you saw that [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) takes a second parameter, you'd need to specify the ignore flag when the regex object is constructed.

Comment: Strange I had the same with IE/Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work, you either need to write inline like this: /myphrase/gi or pass the [RegExp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) object for phrase.match(), like below:

```
var search = new RegExp(keyword[j], "gi");
phrase.match(search) ? match = true : match = false;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I've been tearing my hair off trying to find a solution